# Verb: "to make an incorrect statement"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What's the verb that means: to make an anecdotal statement (based on casual observations) as if it were a fact?

I don't think it's *"to lie"* because this person believes it's the truth. He is unknowingly stating a fallacy.

Comment: Knowingly? Or unknowingly? Or regardless?

Comment: That would be **lie**. Or if you want longer words more applicable to anecdote-telling, **fabricate** or **fantasise**.

Comment: Updated question...hopefully with enough context. Thanks.

Comment: Gossip? (Not a verb, but ["pants on fire"](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/rulings/pants-fire/) fits.)

Comment: @Gnawme, indeed a good fit!

Comment: I vote for ‘fabulate’.

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unknowingly stating a fallacy might be *to err*, *to make a mistake*, *to be mistaken*, or *to be wrong*.  None of those necessarily tie to the "mak[ing] an anecdotal statement...as if it were fact" part of your question, but they're good, general words which don't impute intent the way *to lie* does.

Treating an anecdote as fact might be *overgeneralizing*.

Answer (score 2):

You could, perhaps, *misspeak*, but that has more an idea of "accidentally stating incorrectly or inappropriately", like if you use the name of the person you are addressing in place of the person you're supposed to be speaking about.

Either *misstate* or *misreport*, on the other hand, appears to be more appropriate.